# Can you have multiple SCSS files for a site [foundation]

Tags: html, css, sass, zurb-foundation

I'm curious as to how to create multiple SCSS files in foundation . I'm importing a website as a demonstration on my site and the css would be monstrous if I kept that in one file.

Also do you guys even recommend I use separate SCSS files, so should I just keep everything on one file or multiple files. Thanks again for baring with me through this question .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have multiple SCSS files -- I'm assuming of course you mean non-partial SCSS files (they don't start with an underscore)

Recently I did some work on a website that had 2 main SCSS files and a few smaller ones.

1. critical.scss was definitions needed to make the page load correctly --- these were the things needed for the basic layout of the website to work, and not have a Flash of Unstyled Content -- these were injected into the page in a `<style>` tag.
2. main.scss was the SCSS file responsible for components that were used randomly throughout the site, but were not necessarily critical for the page to look and feel correct.
3. the other styles were one off uses, specific to a page or included on mobile only.

Really it just depends on what you are doing, and what you want done.

Answer (score 0):

You sure can!

you simply put `@import <pathToFile>` in your scss! The docs for this feature are here: http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-5

As to would I recommend it? I sure would, it keeps your styles readable and short. Nothing easier than finding a file called `_buttons.scss` to find the button styles =)

Answer (score 0):

You must separate your SCSS in multiple file, it's easier to read. You can organize with multiple folders (layouts, components, helpers, plugins, variables) and at the end compile you compile in one CSS file.

Take a look about SMACSS and dig in foundation SCSS sources to understand how it works.